# Poco Option with optional argument

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I have a Poco (v1.9.4) based class

```
class PreprocessingApp : public Poco::Util::Application
```

with these 2 methods:

```
void PreprocessingApp::defineOptions(OptionSet& options)
{
    Application::defineOptions(options);

    options.addOption(
        Option("proxy", "p", "Proxify connection")
        .required(false)
        .repeatable(false)
        .argument("the value", false)
        .callback(OptionCallback<PreprocessingApp>(this, &PreprocessingApp::handleBooleanOption))
    );

    options.addOption(
        Option("test", "t", "Test something")
        .required(true)
        .repeatable(false)
        .callback(OptionCallback<PreprocessingApp>(this, &PreprocessingApp::handleBooleanOption))
    );
}

void PreprocessingApp::handleBooleanOption(const string& name, const string& value)
{
    bool actualValue = value.empty() | value == "true" | value == "1";
    config().setBool(name, actualValue);
}
```

As you can see, "proxy" is a boolean option. I added ".argument("the value", false)" to allow passing argument with this option, but flagged the "required" as false to make it optional.
That way I hoped to allow this functionality:

```
PreprocessingApp [-p [value]] -t [value]
```

Both variants should work:

```
PreprocessingApp -p -t 
PreprocessingApp -p true -t
```

In reality, when debugging handleBooleanOption, the "value" is always empty "".
When switching required to true (.argument("the value", true)), the "value" is "-t" and next option processing is omitted.

Is there any solution to get it work as intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Poco [documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Util.OptionProcessor.html):

> Option arguments can be specified in three ways. If a Unix short
> option ("-o") is given, the argument directly follows the option name,
> without any delimiting character or space ("**-ovalue**"). In default
> option mode, or if a Unix long option ("--option") is given, the
> option argument is delimited from the option name with either an equal
> sign ('=') or a colon (':'), as in "**--option=value**" or
> "**/option:value**". Finally, a **required option argument** can be specified
> on the command line after the option, **delimited with a space**, as in
> "**--option value**" or "**-o value**". The latter only works for required
> option arguments, not optional ones.

Basically a required argument needs a space between the name and value whilst an optional one doesn't. So for your optional argument, specify it like this: `-ptrue` or `--proxytrue` or `--proxy:true`.

For the required argument, there's another issue here. You would have thought that using the setter `.required(true)` with `Poco::Util::Option` would be enough to define a required argument in the code, but apparently not. You also have to use the setter `.argument()`, which by default sets `required` to true:

```
Option & argument(
    const std::string & name,
    bool required = true
);
```

So change your code for the required argument to:

```
options.addOption(
    Poco::Util::Option("test", "t", "Test something")
        .required(true)
        .repeatable(false)
        .argument("test")
        .callback(Poco::Util::OptionCallback<ModbusInterface>(this, &ModbusInterface::handleBooleanOption))
    );
```

Then you should be able to call your application like this, for example:

```
PreprocessingApp -ptrue -t true
```

Comment: Can I also provide a required arguments delimited with colon sign?